# add the active class to the selected item

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to change the active class to the selected item but i could not did it right i've searched on google and here on stack overflow as well and i found the toggle() method so i give it a go on my code but i think i didn't use it right 
here is my code:
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <body>
<nav class="main-nav">
  <div class="logo">
    <p class="text">company logo</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="main-nav-items">
    <li class="main-nav-item active" onclick="active()">home</li>
    <li class="main-nav-item active" onclick="active()">contact</li>
    <li class="main-nav-item active" onclick="active()">about</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-nav{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.main-nav-items{
  display: flex;
  width: 1200px;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: center;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 10px;
}
.main-nav-item{
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.main-nav li.active{
  background-color: #542188;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;

}

.main-nav-item:hover{
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: white;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function active(){
  var items=document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav-item");
    for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
      items[i].classList=items[i].classList.replace("active","")
    }
   document.querySelector(".main-nav-item").classList.toggle("active");

}
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

first add Jquery to your html doc like this

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <body>
<nav class="main-nav">
  <div class="logo">
    <p class="text">company logo</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="main-nav-items">
    <li class="main-nav-item" onclick="active(1)" id="1">home</li>
    <li class="main-nav-item" onclick="active(2)" id="2">contact</li>
    <li class="main-nav-item" onclick="active(3)" id="3">about</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script
 src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
 integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- here is jquery plugin -->
 <script>
function active(id){
$("#"+id).on("click",function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
      });
}


 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<li class="main-nav-item active" onclick="active(this)">home</li>
<li class="main-nav-item active" onclick="active(this)">contact</li>
<li class="main-nav-item active" onclick="active(this)">about</li>
```

you need to pass the element that was clicked, to get a reference on which element would remain to be active.

```
function active(target){
    /* this block is to remove all the active class on all main-nav-item
     * [if this scenario is the one you really needed to do
     *    else remove this part]
     */
    var items=document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav-item");
    for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
       items[i].classList.remove("active");
    }

    /* use the parameter "target" on which you passed using the html code 
     * "onclick(this)" and toggle the class "active" 
     */
    target.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

PS.

if all your main-nav-item has the same flow,
you could use, "querySelectorAll" to get all the `main-nav-item` and from there, add an event listener for click, and you remove all the "onclick" on your HTML

```html
  <ul class="main-nav-items">
    <li class="main-nav-item active">home</li>
    <li class="main-nav-item active">contact</li>
    <li class="main-nav-item active">about</li>
  </ul>
```

```
    var mainNavItems = document.querySelectorAll(".main-nav-item");

    Array.forEach(mainNavItems, function( navItem ) {
       navItem.addEventListener("click", function(){
            /* again, you could remove this block of codes, if you
             * just intend to toggle the active class */
              var items=document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav-item");
              for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
                items[i].classList.remove("active");
              }


            this.classList.toggle("active");
       });
    });
```